# Not able to log complete SOAP message in SOAPHandler

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I have created a SOAPHandler at client side to  log outgoing request to server & added a SOAP header in SOAP message.It is logging the outgoing soap xml without the header part .But at the server end I am able to log the whole message with soap header.

Server side log :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <Credential xmlns="http://soap.header.test.com" password="123" username="ashok"/>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<S:Body>
    <ns2:addNumber xmlns:ns2="http://service.ashok.com/">
        <arg0>10</arg0>
        <arg1>200</arg1>
    </ns2:addNumber>
</S:Body>
```

Client side log

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/> **NO HEADER**
<S:Body>
    <ns2:addNumber xmlns:ns2="http://service.ashok.com/">
        <arg0>10</arg0>
        <arg1>200</arg1>
    </ns2:addNumber>
</S:Body>
```

My partial SOAPHandler at client side

```
if (outgoingRequest) {
    SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
    SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
    if (null == header) {
      header = envelope.addHeader();
    }
    QName credential = new QName("http://soap.header.test.com","Credential");
    SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = header.addHeaderElement(credential);
    QName username = new QName("username");
    headerElement.addAttribute(username, "ashok");
    QName password = new QName("password");
    headerElement.addAttribute(password, "123");

    message.writeTo(System.out);
  }
```

Please suggest me how to log SOAP message with header part at client side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you are calling *writeTo* after the message is modified but you still print the old version (without any header change). I suggest you to use [saveChanges](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#saveChanges%28%29) method from SOAPMessage

> abstract  void saveChanges()
>
> Updates this SOAPMessage object with all the changes that have been made to it.

And then try to call the method *writeTo*. let me know if that works.

I tried your code as:

```
EchoServiceImplService echoService = new EchoServiceImplService();
        HandlerResolver resolver = new HandlerResolver(){

            @Override
            public List<Handler> getHandlerChain(PortInfo portInfo){
                List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>();
                handlers.add(new LogMessageHandler());
                return handlers;
            }
        };
        echoService.setHandlerResolver(resolver);
        EchoService port = echoService.getEchoServiceImplPort();
```

And

```
public class LogMessageHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context){
        try {
            if ((Boolean) context.get(SOAPMessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY)) {
                SOAPMessage message = context.getMessage();
                SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
                SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
                if (null == header)
                    header = envelope.addHeader();

                QName credential = new QName("http://soap.header.test.com", "Credential");
                SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = header.addHeaderElement(credential);
                QName username = new QName("username");
                headerElement.addAttribute(username, "ashok");
                QName password = new QName("password");
                headerElement.addAttribute(password, "123");

                message.writeTo(System.out);
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("An error in handler occurs.");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And I'm able to see the full SOAPMesssage at client side, just call the handler before send the request to the server.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Header>
   <Credential xmlns="http://soap.header.test.com" password="123" username="ashok"/></S:Header>
<S:Body>
   <ns2:echo xmlns:ns2="http://echo.soap.ws.jax.koitoer.com/">
       <arg0>Koitoer echo </arg0>
   </ns2:echo>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: I don't see your use of `saveChanges` in your code sample

Comment: Thanks saveChanges() worked ..


    message.saveChanges();
    message.writeTo(System.out);

Comment: the solution is call to method saveChanges after writeTo (method to print message). 
  context.getMessage().saveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

The solution is call to method saveChanges after method writeTo.

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);
    if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) { // outbound: request to send
        try {

            SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
            if (header == null)
                header = envelope.addHeader();

            SOAPElement soapSecurity = header.addChildElement("Security", "wsse",
                    "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            soapSecurity.setAttribute(header.getPrefix() + ":mustUnderstand", "true");

            ...

            context.getMessage().saveChanges();
            context.getMessage().writeTo(System.out);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        // inbound: response received
    }
    return true;
}
```

Sorry for my english.

Greeting.